# Dexie, Async filter function for filtering by another table

Tags: dexie

Is there a way to filter using a foreign column using `.and()` or `.filter()`? Because sorting as such would require using an async function`

```js
const oPs = await context.orderProducts
    .where('product')
    .anyOf(productIds)
    .and(async (item) => {
        const order = await context.orders
            .where('orderProducts')
            .equals(item.id)
            .and((order) => {
                return order.status === 'open';
            })
            .first();
        return order !== undefined;
    })
    .toArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to use async function in filter or and(), and it would not be as performant as turning around the query like this instead:

```js
// Query open orders
const myOrders = await context.orders
  .where({status: 'open'}) // Utilize index
  .toArray();

// Query orderProducts of the open orders:
const orderProductIds = myOrders.map(o => o.orderProducts);
const orderProducts = await context.orderProducts
  .bulkGet(orderProductIds);

// Filter manually on the given productIds array
const oPs = orderProducts.filter(op => productIds.includes(op.product));
```